# SmackConfiguration.setDefaultPacketReplyTimeout -- throwing error

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

I am writing a simple XMPP client for Android have used the following code to establish a connection with an XMPP server :

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException.NotConnectedException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.chat.ChatManager;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.chat.Chat;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.chat.ChatMessageListener;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.Intent;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    String msg = "PM1139 : ";

    SmackConfiguration.setDefaultPacketReplyTimeout(10000);
    XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration config2 = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
            .setUsernameAndPassword("xxx", "xxxxxx")
            .setServiceName("adastra.re")
            .setHost("adastra.re")
            .setPort(5222)
            .setResource("Android")
            .build();

    AbstractXMPPConnection conn1 = new XMPPTCPConnection(config2);
```

Everything works fine EXCEPT the line :

```
SmackConfiguration.setDefaultPacketReplyTimeout(10000);
```

which throws an error

> Multiple markers at this line
>     - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced    construct(s)
>     - Syntax error on token "10000", delete this     token

If I remove this line, the program works fine except that once in a while I get a timeout. Hence I wanted to set a long timeout ~ 10 sec.

I have seen this construct used in many places and have even used this myself elsewhere.

I had first thought that this was Eclipse (ver 3.8, running on Ubuntu 14.04) acting weird, so I refreshed the project, restarted Eclipse, even restarted the machine, but no joy. Error is persistent.

What else could do?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple. 
the line of code needs to be shifted into the OnCreate(..) method in the MainActivity Class. Thats all

```
@Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
          SmackConfiguration.setDefaultPacketReplyTimeout(10000);
          Log.d(msg, "The onCreate() event");
       }
```

This solves the problem